# NRF24L01+ and NRF24LU1+ Communication - RFID application

Tags: rfid, nrf24l01

I have an RFID application in which tag has NRF24LU1+ and the Reader has NRF24L01+ chip. The Reader is based on STM32F4xx Micro-controller.

I have two same Readers which are communicating with themselves, one as RF transmitter and other as RF receiver.

I have two same tags which are communicating with each other, one as RF transmitter and another as RF receiver.

The frequency range of the nordic chips is 2.4 to 2.525 GHz. The problem I have is the Reader is not communicating with the tag, the Reader as Receiver and tag as transmitter. Data rate selected is 2Mbps, channel is 2, payload is 5. These settings are common between tag and Reader. I am not sure if I am giving correct address for TX and Rx.

The registers TX_ADDR, RX_ADDR_P0(Pipe 0), RX_ADDR_P1(Pipe 1) are updated for address on a device as I know.
I tried:

(Reader)

RX : TX_ADDR = 0xE7E7E7E7E7,
     RX_ADDR_P0 = 0xE7E7E7E7E7,
     RX_ADDR_P1 = 0xC2C2C2C2C2.

(Tag)

TX: TX_ADDR = 0xC2C2C2C2C2,
    RX_ADDR_P0 = 0xC2C2C2C2C2,
    RX_ADDR_P1 = 0xE7E7E7E7E7.

Is this the correct address setting? Am I missing something.?

Answer (score 1):

Address settings looks fine to me.
Please, check they are communicating on the same channel, they are in the range and you have correctly initialized TX while other nRF24 is in RX mode.

Comment: Thanks, we found the problem was in hardware, software settings were fine only. Thanks for stopping by.